# What are the best practices for defining workflow for documentation and localization tasks in JIRA?

Tags: workflow, jira

Almost every issue needs a documentation subtask.

Many issues need a localization subtask.

Should documentation and localization issues have their own workflow (by issue type)?

Should each project have documentation and localization components, so that those issues would be automatically assigned to the component owner?

Should "Create Issue" screen have a checkbox "Needs documentation", which would create a documentation subtask with specific fields?

Answer (score 0):

I have a different understanding for working with JIRA. For me, JIRA helps me understand when I have to do something, what the status is, and when I'm done with it. When documentation and localization is every time necessary, I would not like to overflow my JIRA with all these sub-tasks everyone understands that they are necessary.

The only reasons, why these should be extracted as sub-tasks (and managed with a workflow) are:

- You have normally a different assignee for documentation and / or localization, so you are able to assign that to a different person.
- Their workflow is different, therefore you want to manage it separately.

I would not expect additional components for them, because when you want to isolate them, just have a custom field for it (or create a sub-task like work item for documentation and localization, don't know if that is easily possible).

I would not add that "Needs documentation" flag, because people that add issues often don't know if documentation is necessary. So no, I would not add them as sub-tasks, neither as additional flag, but explain everyone that documentation and localization is necessary. There should be ways to check that automatically, without any issue ...

And of course, you are free to add a documentation screen with additional custom fields. There you could document in implementing the issue what you have done about documentation and internationalization. So checking that these are empty, would replace the flag you have mentioned.

Comment: >>everyone understands that they are necessary<< - that makes tasks being done depending on a person "being a good guy". The point of automated workflow is to automatically enforce the required tasks.

Comment: "Needs documentation" flag would be on "Implement" screen, assigned to a developer.

Answer (score 0):

I agree, only create issues or subissues for work that occurs in parallel and needs a different assignee or due date or such. If the work happens in every case then build it into the workflow instead.

The other thing to be aware of is that whatever is entered in a field such as "Notes for Documentation" always needs human review before being sent to a customer.